# error: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID with fetch () in web

Tags: javascript, .net, https, fetch-api

I am making a web in .net and I need to call an API, the API has https and others but when calling it it returns the following error:

> ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

my code to call it from JavaScript is the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            const tokenUsuario = $('.tokenUsuario').text();
           

            (async () => {
                const rawResponse = await fetch('https://rutaApi/api/metodo', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        'token': tokenUsuario
                    }, 
                });
                const content = await rawResponse.json();

                console.log(content);
            })();

        });
```

From the Postman it works for me, but I had to give something to disable ssl verification so that it would work for me in the postman, does anyone know how I can make it work for me on my website?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?